# I'm having trouble displaying the output from the code

Tags: c#

Create a class called Employee that includes three pieces of information as either instance variables or auto-implemented properties - first name (type string), last name (type string) and a monthly salary (decimal). Your class should have a constructor that initializes the three values. Provide a property with a get and set block for any instance variables. If the monthly salary is negative, the set block should leave the instance variable unchanged. Write a test driver program for Employee that demonstrates the Employee class capabilities (use Program.cs for this). Create 3 Employee objects and display each object’s yearly salary. Then give each Employee a 10% raise and display each Employee’s yearly salary again.

Here's what i did so far:
part 1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace EmployeeDB
{
    class Employee
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        private decimal salary;

        //constructor
        public Employee[string firstName string lastName decimal salary]
        {
            FirstName = firstName;
            LastName  = lastName;
            Salary = salary

        }  
        public decimal Salary
        {
            get { return salary; }
            set
            {
                if (value >= 0)
                    salary = value;
            }
        }   
    }
```

Comment: I have a second part of the code that goes with it but it won't let me post it

Comment: so what exactly is the question?

Comment: If you want to show some output, you need to do it with `Console.WriteLine` or similar, in the main method of your application, after creating the objects

Comment: How many marks do I get for doing your assignment? Where is the rest of the code you have written so far?

Comment: `public Employee[string firstName string lastName decimal salary]` isn't c#. I think you mean `public Employee(string firstName, string lastName, decimal salary)`.

Comment: I need help with the second part of the code but it won't let me post the question.